# can you validate xsd against xml in vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd

How do I validate an xml document against an xsd in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open you XML file in VS2010; in the Properties tool window (F4) there is a Schemas property. List the XSD you want in there. Once done, the errors/warnings will show up in the Error List tool window.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need. First the XML Document must be associated with the Schema:

```
<XmlDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Code\Schema.xsd">
</XmlDocument>
```

Now you need to have that Schema XSD Added into your Project. Now when you open the XML Document you should get intellisence and errors / warnings shown as you would errors in your normal C#/VB/etc/ code.

Comment: Hi Dave, you don't need to modify the XML to get what you described (see my answer, I get I beat you by seconds ;)... in fact, VS2010 is "smart" enough that even if you close and reopen the file, it'll remember the values you've set in the Properties window. You also get Intellisense....

Comment: Never knew that, all ours had the path set :)